# Error: Converting circular structure to JSON from data being returned from external axios api call

Tags: json, express, axios, routes, response

i am currently making an api call in my express server via the `/services` route. For the most part, the code seems to be working fine but on occasion, i get an error stating the following:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'httpsAgent' -> object with constructor 'Agent'
    |     property 'sockets' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     ...
    |     property 'errored' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    --- property 'config' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
```

does anyone know what could possibly be causing this issue? I'll also be including the routes snippet below that deals with the `/services` route. I believe if anything the issue could be persisting with the line `res.status(200).json(response.data);`

```
const express = require('express'); 
const router = express.Router();
const axios = require('axios');
const https = require('https');

router.post('/services', function(req, res){

    const { gender, age } = req.body;
    console.log("req", req.body);

    const agent = new https.Agent({  
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    });

    axios({
        method: "GET",
        url: "baseURL",
        httpsAgent: agent,
        params: {
            key: 'key',
            age: age,
            gender: gender,
        },
    }).then(response => {
        var data = response.data;
        res.status(200).json(response.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).json({ message: err });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: What version of Axios are you using? I'd say the problem is in your error handler `.json({ message: err })` but that was fixed in [this PR](https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/1625)

Comment: according to my `package.json` file, i am currently using `"axios": "^0.25.0"`. If its due to the version should i just get rid of the error handler then?

Comment: Maybe just send a message instead of the entire `err` object. I'd also raise an issue in the Axios Github repo. They seem to have missed a circular reference in `error.toJSON()`, perhaps something to do with the custom agent

Comment: I see, so for the meanwhile use something like `.catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).json("error");
    });` instead?

Comment: I was thinking `.json({ message: err.message })` but yeah, whatever you want. The circular reference is definitely coming from `err` though so it only happens when the request fails

Comment: I see, so if that's the case what could possibly be causing the request to fail at that point? It works majority of the time though it hiccups i guess from time to time which doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I [created an issue on Axios for this](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4486). As for why it fails, you'll need more debugging information. Could be rate limiting blocking your requests. See https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors

Comment: actually, i just viewed the issue and it seems to be an ECONNRESET. which i guess is dealing with rate limiting blocking your requests? how exactly do you address that on a route?